# Why can't I use focus() to place a cursor inside of a text field outside of Firefox?

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm using this line of code:

```
$(":text:visible:enabled:first").focus();
```

It works in Firefox but not in Chrome, IE8, IE7, or Safari. I would ideally like to place the cursor in a text field at a form so that one may just starting typing in the field without having to navigate to it with a mouse.

Comment: Works for me... Try a simple test page, see if you can reproduce it outside your project.

Answer (score 1):

That should work... Try debugging using any JS debugger. I *bet* you're having some JS error preventing the rest of the code to continue in other browsers.

Also, old school debugging - try this line right before your `focus()` one:

```
alert( $(":text:visible:enabled:first").length );
```

That should alert `1`. If you don't get any alert box, then that line is not being reached at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the text field id and use that. The text field would look like:

```
<input type="text" id="mytextfield" />
```

And the script would look like this:

```
$(function(){
    // On Page Load
    $('#mytextfield').focus();
});
```